# custom sort order on array of objects where the objects are different lengths and dynamic

Tags: javascript, typescript

The objects are pulled from the backend, the objects can be different lengths and can contain different values.

I want to custom sort these objects in this order of the array below:

```
let array = ["packhouse", "location", "date", "time"]
```

this is what I can do (searching through the web):

```
var myArray = [{
    name: 'packhouse'
  },
  {
    name: 'notPackhouse',
    date: "date"
  },
  {
    name: 'a'
  },
];

myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return array.indexOf(a.name) - sortOrder.indexOf(b.name);
});
```

the data being pulled doesnt always have "packhouse" or could be a bigger length than the custom order array. is there a better solution for this?

Comment: So you want to sort your objects based on the value of the `name` property, in accordance with the first array?

Comment: What about items of `myArray` missing from `array`?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be a [mre] since it [has typographical and other errors](https://tsplay.dev/wRJavw).  Could you fix those?  Additionally, you should explain exactly what input/output relationship you're looking for (e.g.,  what order do you expect `myArray` to be in after you sort it), and whether or not the code you have here actually produces it or not.  If it works the way you want, then you should explain why you want a "better" solution; if it does not, you should be able to show what it does wrong.